# How to place a specific div before other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a situation where I need to place `<div id="content1">` just before `<div id="content2">`, but `<div id="content2">` is inside another div so css with push pull won't work here.
Here is my HTML structure:

```html
<div class="col span_3_of_4">
  <div class="col span_3_of_4">
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <div class="fr">
      <a href="/" class="pdfgen funcicons" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="/" class="print funcicons"></a>
      <a href="/" class="tsign funcicons"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="formatedtext text">
    <div id="content2">
      <p>Content that needs to below content2 id</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 mlfix">
      <div id="datepick"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_2_of_3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

How to place whole `<div id="content1"></div>` before `<div id="content2"></div>`? Any good or dirty examples are welcomed.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Comment: Any particular reason why the HTML generator can't handle this one? Solving it any other way would be fragile :(

Comment: Since you tagged your question with jquery, you can use : `$("#content1").insertBefore($("#content2"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). We will have to target the parent of `content2`, insert `content1`, and use `content2` again as a reference point:

```js
const content1 = document.getElementById('content1')
const content2 = document.getElementById('content2')

content2.parentNode.insertBefore(content1, content2)
```

```html
<div class="col span_3_of_4">
  <div class="col span_3_of_4">
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_4">
    <div class="fr">
      <a href="/" class="pdfgen funcicons" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="/" class="print funcicons"></a>
      <a href="/" class="tsign funcicons"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="formatedtext text">
    <div id="content2">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 mlfix">
      <div id="datepick">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_2_of_3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

Note, I have added in some text to make it clearer that the nodes have in fact moved.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @twelvell No problem. If you need any more help, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine by having the `#content1` before `<div class="formatedtext text">` you can use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

On the parent `<div class="col span_3_of_4">` or you can wrap the `<div class="formatedtext text">` & `<div id="content1">` and use `display: flex;` on it.

Then use the propriety `order` on the element `<div class="formatedtext text">` and give the value 2, so it will place after `<div id="content1"></div>`

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/uvkdabor/1/